# increase the size of the bubbles created by the plot_ly() where mode = "markers"

Tags: r, plotly

```
plot_ly(ProdSummary, x = logMetricRevenue2016, y = MarginPercent2016,
        mode = "markers" , axes=F , size = (Quantity2016), color=Brand, text=paste("P_Code",product_code))
```

the bubbleschart produced shows small bubbles and I could do `size=Quantity2016*100`, but that doesn't increase size of the bubbles on the chart. Its all relative.

Comment: Try `marker = list(size = Quantity2016*100)`.  **Note** that you also need to add some data and format your question into a minimal working example. As it stands it is likely to be flagged for removal, because it is not reproducible. please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), and [read the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to get a better understanding of how to ask question on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `sizeref` and `sizemode` under `marker`. Especially play around with different values of `sizeref`:

```
trace = go.Scatter(x=x,
                   y=y, 
                   mode='markers',
                   marker=dict(
                               size=[abs(i) for i in Quantity2016],
                               sizeref=0.1,
                               sizemode='area'
                              )
                   )
```

---

*Just to note, negative values for* `size` *in your* `Quantity2016` *list will make those point disappear (or I suppose be plotted as size 0), so just be aware of that.*